# GSM/GPRS AT command - hitting a link

Tags: communication, gsm, at-commands

I am trying to target a specific page (script) on my webserver using a GPRS modem. I can hit my domain, and get a reply back but then when I am trying to call my script it just won't let me:

```
AT

OK 
AT+CPIN?

+CPIN: READY 

OK

AT+SFUN=SID

+ICCID: 54646149798787496

AT+CSQ

+CSQ: 16,99

OK

AT+AIPDCONT=“wap.rogers.com"


OK

AT+AIPA=1

+AIPA: 1,10.110.234.135,0,0,0 ;Connect with APN server

OK

AT+AIPO=1,,“www.Myserver.com”,80,0,,1

+AIPO: 1,“10.110.234.135”,4770,“74.125.227.17”,80,0,30,1,0,64000,8,7300,5720,-500,0) 


OK
```

I am trying to hit either "MYSRVR.COM/SUB/PAGE.PY" or I can even do with "MYSRVR.COM/SUB/" if that's too much of a hassle.

Ref to [AT commands/Data sheet](http://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Sensors/GPS/GSM_GPRS_Enhanced_AT_Command_V1%208.pdf)

Comment: Have you tried doing so via other computer ?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by other computer?

Comment: The question is OK here IMO but something you should add is the kind of GPRS modem and a link to a datasheet or command documentation, the AT commands used for TCP/IP level comms tends to vary a bit.

Comment: You say "I can hit my domain and get a reply back", I assume you did that via some other computer in your LAN( by pointing your browser to 'the' url). Can you similarly evoke your page.py script using this method ? That will reveal errors, if any.

Comment: Well the reason that I am saying it works ok is the AT's respond on the 3rd line. but to answer your question, yes, I have tested the server and the script and it works OK on a browser, but I believe there is a different technique to opening a page via AT

Comment: Can you provide the sequence of AT commands you are using ! Something like *AT+CLPORT*, *AT+CIPSTART* and *AT+CIPSEND* commands for achieving TCP connections.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about electronic design.

Comment: @vvy I'll update the post and add the full AT commands

Comment: @LeonHeller off-topic because it's not about electronic design? Maybe you are interested in [this club](http://xkcd.com/703/)

Answer (score 1):

You're opening the socket OK but the part you're missing is that you'll need to issue an HTTP request to the server. The full documentation you'll probably want to look at is [RFC2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) but the request should look roughly like this:

```
GET /SUB/PAGE.PY HTTP/1.1
Host: www.MYSERVR.com
(blank line)
```

The above probably violates a few standards because there are additional headers I believe you should include, but it should give you a pointer in the right direction. Maybe for a start install a Telnet client and try connecting that way rather than using a web browser so you can check that the request works OK and easily check the response you get back.

You need to send the above over the socket, so for that module take a look at `AT+AIPW` command.

Answer (score 1):

I think you *need* to send a Http **GET** header after you are connected to the server. Something like

```
At+AIPW=1, "GET /SUB/ HTTP/1.1 \r\n Host: www.YOURSERVR.com \r\n User-Agent: Myzilla \r\n \r\n "
```

The datasheet you mentioned suggests one other method too i.e.

```
AT+AIPW=1,x
..response "CONNECT"
"x bytes of data"
```

Those *x bytes* should have a valid GET/POST header.

The server response shall follow the last step.

Comment: yeah this sounds more reasonable. I'll give this a try